# jquery files included in my php file not working on server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i have included `jquery.js`, `jscript.js` it works fine locally
but when i uploaded `jscript.js` is not running
jscript.js has only one line that is

```
$().ready(function(){
 alert (9);
});
```

Comment: Share your code with us, please, We can't help you without information.

Comment: Did you check your JavaScript console for errors?  (P.S. `$().ready` is *not* recommended, try `$(function(){})` or `$(document).ready(` instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by replacing

```
<script src="folderOnMyPc/local/jquery.js">
```

with

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
```

Answer (score 1):

First off change $().ready to $(document).ready and then the next thing to check for is:

1. Are you including the jquery library prior to loading your jscript.js?
2. Are you including jscript.js in the HTML page?

Comment: 1- yes i have included jquery library prior to jscript

Comment: 2- i hv inculded both .js files in php file

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   
<head>   
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
<title>Urdu Fonts Demonstration</title>   
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscript.js"></script>   
</head>   
<body>   this is body   </body>   </html>

Comment: Check if the scripts are erroring out when loaded.  In firefox/chrome you can do this by pressing ctrl+shift+j once page has been loaded.  Check if there are any errors.

Comment: solved by including jquery.js from jquery.com/.... not my own file